# How to use tidycensus API to combine race data of 3 states into 1 dataframe and then use spread function to create columns for each racial group?

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to R and am now learning the tidycensus API in class

First thing I did was take the example of the state of NY:

```
racevars <- c(White = "P2_005N", 
              Black = "P2_006N", 
              Asian = "P2_008N", 
              Hispanic = "P2_002N")

ny <- get_decennial(
  geography = "tract",
  variables = racevars,
  state = "NY",
  geometry = TRUE,
  summary_var = "P2_001N",
  year = 2020
) 

head(ny)

ny %>%
  mutate(percent = 100 * (value / summary_value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = percent)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  geom_sf(color = NA) +
  theme_void() + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c() + 
  labs(fill = "% of population\n(2020 Census)")

ny <- get_acs(geography = "tract", 
              variables = "B19013_001",
              state = "NY", 
              county = , 
              year = 2020, 
              geometry = TRUE)
```

That got me a picture that separated 4 maps of NY with a heat map of population distribution

I did something similar with NJ and CT:

```
nj <- get_decennial(
  geography = "tract",
  variables = racevars,
  state = "NJ",
  geometry = TRUE,
  summary_var = "P2_001N",
  year = 2020
) 

head(nj)

nj %>%
  mutate(percent = 100 * (value / summary_value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = percent)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  geom_sf(color = NA) +
  theme_void() + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c() + 
  labs(fill = "% of population\n(2020 Census)")

nj <- get_acs(geography = "tract", 
              variables = "B19013_001",
              state = "NJ", 
              county = , 
              year = 2020, 
              geometry = TRUE)

ct <- get_decennial(
  geography = "tract",
  variables = racevars,
  state = "CT",
  geometry = TRUE,
  summary_var = "P2_001N",
  year = 2020
) 

head(ct)

ct %>%
  mutate(percent = 100 * (value / summary_value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = percent)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  geom_sf(color = NA) +
  theme_void() + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c() + 
  labs(fill = "% of population\n(2020 Census)")

ct <- get_acs(geography = "tract", 
              variables = "B19013_001",
              state = "CT", 
              county = , 
              year = 2020, 
              geometry = TRUE)
```

However, I'm stuck on trying to merge and rename columns

Trying to merge them like:

```
total <- merge(ny, nj, ct, by="variable")
```

Or another column given just tells me something like:

```
Error in merge(ny, nj, ct, by = "variable") : 
  unused arguments (ct, by = "variable")
```

Changing only column name

I've also tried:

```
total <- list(ny, nj, ct)
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the objects returned from `tidycensus` are of class `sf` with the same number of columns. You can combine them into a dataframe using `rbind`.

```
do.call("rbind", list(nj, ct, ny))
```

It does not make sense to merge the objects in this case because you do not have common observations on which to join them. Regardless, your call with `merge` fails because the function only accepts two objects, not three.